# How encryption is performed for NetTcpBinding + Transport security + Windows authentication

Tags: .net, wcf, security, ssl, encryption

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms729700(v=vs.110).aspx) states that:

> The NetTcpBinding class uses TCP for message transport. Security for the transport mode is provided by implementing Transport Layer Security (TLS) over TCP. The TLS implementation is provided by the operating system.

And also:

> If you are using Windows security, a certificate is not required.

Does it mean that in case of using NetTcpBinding + Transport security + Windows authentication I don’t need to explicitly install any certificates (neither server, nor client side) and don't have to specify any certificates  in binding?

If I understand correctly TLS, it is based on public-key cryptography. That is - one party encrypts data with public key, and another decrypts it using it's private key.

So, if my reasoning is correct, then where do those keys come from, using WCF in this configuration?

Comment: I found answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187604/how-does-nettcpbindingread-windowsstreamsecuritybindingelement-encrypt-sign-me